# Проверить массив объектов на null

Tags: javascript

Массив объектов надо проверить на наличие `null`, если в ключе `status` пришел `null` его надо перезаписать объектом с ключами `ID` и `NAME` c пустыми строками.

```
let arr = [
  {
    name: "Ivan",
    age: 23,
    status: {
      id: 1,
      name: "OK"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Egor",
    age: 24,
    status: {
      id: 2,
      name: "FAIL"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Ivan",
    age: 23,
    status: null
  }
];
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
let arr = [{
    name: "Ivan",
    age: 23,
    status: {
      id: 1,
      name: "OK"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Egor",
    age: 24,
    status: {
      id: 2,
      name: "FAIL"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Ivan",
    age: 23,
    status: null
  }
];

arr.forEach(e => e.status ? {} : e.status = {
  id: '',
  name: ''
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

На Вашем месте я бы не перезаписывал объект, а создавал новый. Это более верный подход с точки зрения функционального программирования и с точки зрения чистого кода.

```
const normalizedArr = arr.map(item => item.status ? item : { 
    ...item, 
    status: { 
       id: '', 
       name: '' 
    }
});
```